# Routes not working without index.php in laravel 4.2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel-4

I have spent a considerable amount of time googling for suggestions for this, and despite setting up several test project in Laravel 4.2 before on xampp server.
I am not sure what I am missing in this project...

I have one more project on server and it is working fine But when I tried to start this new project I started getting this error.

XAMPP version 5.6.3
PHP version 5.6.3

This is my .htaccess file :

```
RewriteEngine on
```

Options -MultiViews
    
    RewriteEngine On

```
# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

This is my Routes.php file :

```
Route::get('/admin', function(){
    echo 'hello';
});
```

My url is : 
http://localhost/adminpanel/public/admin

And showing this error :

Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ NotFoundHttpException

When I write this url : http://localhost/adminpanel/public/index.php/admin Now works fine..

Comment: Is `.htaccess` enabled on your server? (`AllowOverride All`)

Comment: @lukasgeiter, Yah already it's enabled..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this htaccess on your public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```